# How to show difference in scatter chart with plots at same position in highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, scatter

Need to show difference between two plots of the same location.
Either by hovering or by tool tip.

```
plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                },
                symbol: "circle"
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span></span>',
                pointFormat: '<b>#{point.req_num} {point.title}</b><br>BV:{point.bv} / FC Effort: {point.fc} / :{point.rom} Hrs'
            },
```

fiddle link :
https://jsfiddle.net/dhamotharanb/hnu2r5j7/4/

Expecting the same as in below image

[image][image]

Is this is achievable in highcharts

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by two points of the same location.  Do you mean you want the difference between the X values for the same Y values?

Comment: Hi Barbara Laird, i meant two plots as points. Added image file for the expectation

Answer (score 0):

By changing `marker.radius` value, disabling `stickyTracking` and setting `tooltip.snap` to low value to be able to hover on two neighboring points.

```
tooltip: {
  snap: 1
}
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.snap
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stickyTracking
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.marker.radius

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8qdnckfg/

Comment: Thanks d_paul, but expectation is radius should be of same size. Added image files for clarification

Comment: From what I can see, they are not positioned in the same place. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgk1Ld7/.